# Fatal error while code checkin to Azure DevOps using git-bash

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-bash

While trying to do code checkin into azure DevOps following the simple git push command after setting remote repository, leads to an error and code not pushed.

Need assistance.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error while code checkin to Azure DevOps using git-bash

if you see an RPC failed error when you git push code to Azure DevOps, please try to review the suggestions in following article:

[RPC failures and http.postBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/rpc-failures-http-postbuffer?view=azure-devops)

- Upgrade Git
- Check hotfixes
- Check if you're using a proxy or load balancer

If above not help you, you can try to set `http.postBuffer`, but make sure you have read the [http.postBuffer questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/rpc-failures-http-postbuffer?view=azure-devops#httppostbuffer-questions)

Hope this helps.